# Can't instantiate new controller

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like to load a new ViewController/View upon validation of a login username/password. I have the following:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
...
...
ViewController *Workflow = [self.storyboard     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Workflow"]; 
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:Workflow animated:YES];
```

Then, in the story board, I added a new view controller and slapped a new uiview on there. I then changed the identifier of the ViewController to "Workflow". However, after clicking this button, nothing happens. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would first NSLog the index of the button sending you the action, it's extremely useful for long alerts, and delegate methods with switch statements. If nothing is happening, then nothing is usually being done.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could be missing a `UINavigationController` from your storyboard.  Unless your view controllers live within a UINavigationController, `pushViewController:` will have no effect.

If this is the case, what you need to do is:

- Drag an instance of UINavigationController from the objects library onto your storyboard.  Delete the root view controller that comes with it.
- With the Navigation Controller selected on the storyboard, click the checkbox named "Is Initial View Controller" on the Attributes Inspector.
- Hold down the Control key on your keyboard and drag with the mouse from the Navigation Controller to your first view controller (presumably the one where you are displaying the alert view) to create a segue.  In the Storyboard Segues box that appears after you release, select "Relationship - Root View Controller"

Comment: Thanks for the concise response. I've put in a navigation controller as the root controller to the view that I'm working with. Am I supposed to add a new ViewController to the navigation controller? If I run the program as described by you, after I press the button that triggers all if this, it freezes and I get a SIGBART error on the autorelease/        

    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

Line of code in my main.m.

Comment: I should note that the output spits out the following:


    2012-02-21 18:11:22.331 HMG[14991:f803] *** Terminating app due       to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing     a navigation controller is not supported'

Comment: The navigation controller should be your initial view controller for your APP, i.e. in storyboard the first arrow should be pointing at this view controller, and the checkbox is initial view controller in the attributes inspector should be checked (that is to say, two ways of doing the same thing.)  You should be pushing your custom view controller (`Workflow` in your example).  It should not itself be a navigation controller.